# Get only those users who cancelled a request two or more time in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, database, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I've two tables

> Providers and User_Requests

I need to get only those providers who have cancelled two or more requests

Providers.php

```
public function trips() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserRequests');
}
```

UserRequests.php

```
public function provider()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Provider');
}
```

How can I get only those providers having 2+ cancel requests?

user_requests table has following columns:

```
provider_id, status
```

where status => enum=('SEARCHING', 'CANCELLED', 'ACCEPTED')

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use:

```
$userRequests = UserRequests::where('status','CANCELLED')
                    ->groupBy('provider_id')
                    ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) >= 2')
                    ->with('provider')
                    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that helped me to get right direction: I used following code to make it working.

Provider::has('cancelled_count', '>=', 2)->get();

while in cancelled_count method I added where conditions.